# Using @BeanProperty or Create Set & Get methods using scala

Tags: spring, hibernate, scala

In scala Using @BeanProperty or Create Set & Get methods   which is the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional programming and Scala in general you should always prefer immutable objects. But if you need to change the object state, then i would stick to (g|s)etters. Cause in this case you can without changing the internal state of the object return a new object with modified state.

```
class MyClass(val name) {
  def setName(newName: String) = new MyClass(newName)
}
```

This way preserves immutability and gives you setters: `setName(String)` and getters: `obj.name`

`@BeanPropery` is used when you need high level of interoperability with some Java code, it helps you quickly generate (g|s)etters for your code, but it has some constraints cause you cannot give the names to this methods which you would like.

Although i recomend to use case classes with copy method:

```
case class Person(name: String, age)
val me = Person("Alex", 23) // create an object
val afterBD = me.copy(age = 24)
```

The same semantics, but purely functional approach without any mutable internal state.

And as for Spring framework in Scala. I've never work with it (thank God =)), but there is a good [post](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala/) on this topic